# What is the preg_replace regex to replace this HTML tag?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

How would I convert strings like this:

```
<span class="it">CONTENT</span>
```

Into this:

```
{it}CONTENT{/it}
```

While keeping CONTENT intact?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<span class="it">(.*?)<\/span>/', '{it}$1{/it}', $text)
```

This is not the most versatile solution, but this works for your code. There is the possibility to have the content of the class attribute as a variable as well, but that won't be too hard to figure out now.

Comment: That works until you have, for example, `<span class='it'>` or `<span id="foo" class="it">` or any number of other variations.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes for examples of the dangers of using regexes for parsing HTML.

Comment: I'm well aware, but that is not what the question required. Parsing HTML has and will always be a pain in the butt. The other solutions are better syntax wise, but all will solve the problem the thread stated.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
 preg_replace('/<span.+class="(.+)">(.+)<\/span>/', '{$1}$2{/$1}', $text);
```

Comment: I needed it to be `<\/span>`

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started:

```
preg_replace('#<span\s*class="(\w*)">(\w*)</span>#i', '{$1}$2{/$1}', $str);
```

Output:

```
{it}CONTENT{/it}
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pN3dY4)